# Jquery, how can you open a new Modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

This should be a simple fix.  I am not sure why myModal won't hide and let the myModal1 take it's place.  It seems like the code is correct, but there must be something I am missing.  I tried narrowing down the code to most base elements.

```
<script>
$(function(){
$(".remove").click(function(){
$('#yes_delete').click(function() {
    $("#myModal").hide();
    $("#myModal1").show();
  }); 
});
</script>


<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="false" href="#myModal" id="15" class="remove" title="Remove"><span class="hidding">Remove</span></a>

<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Are you sure?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>Are you sure you want to <strong>DELETE</strong> this Audit? You will not be able to get it back.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

        <form method="POST">
            <input id="yes_delete" value="Yes " name="deleteaudit" type="button">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        </form> 



        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>





<div class="modal" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Success</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>You have successfully DELETED the audit.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

        <form method="POST">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
        </form> 




        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things - first it seems bad UX / UI to force one modal to close and then open another in the same action - better to have just the one modal and toggle divs that are either shown or hidden.

Second - it is early here and I can't quite focus enough to read your code fully but you are nesting one click event inside another and not closing off the document ready.- which may be why your desired effect isn't occurring. you need just one click handler.

either close the document ready -

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".remove").click(function(){
           $('#yes_delete').click(function() {
               $("#myModal").hide();
              $("#myModal1").show();
           }); 
     });
});
</script>
```

or just have one click handler - Which is the better option. (and then add a second one if you need to but not nested inside the first one.) :

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#yes_delete').click(function() {
         $("#myModal").hide();
        $("#myModal1").show();
     }); 
});
</script>
```

If you want to do one click handler (on the class) then you need to pass an argument (such as id of the button clicked or the value) to distinguish between action a and action b.) And I STRONGLY suggest not switching modals - but toggling divs  - or something similar within the one modal.

Comment: I wasn't even thinking that- you are right!  Divs would be better!

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy coding :))

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/FqLjn84APL I tried your suggestion but am missing something here data-show ="false" didn't seem to work on the intial load.   I tried it on the Div instead of the initial loading of the div.

Comment: i just looked at your bootply and its the same issue as in my post - you are nesting clicks and not closing the document ready - i just removed the "$(".remove").click(function(){" and it worked but still swapped the modals. This works because now the document ready is closed and the event handler on the button is fired on the onclick.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/FqLjn84APL  So I did it the more traditional route... It works with ID's, but how come you can't group them in a class?  I updated the code to show my issue.